# site_config configuration in azure terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

For examples I've seen of a .NET application deployment to azure, people mention the `site_config` parameter, however this doesn't seem to be well explained [in the official docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service#site_config) , only that it's optional. So, I just guessed, seeing the azure interface that this probably is the runtime environment maybe?: [image]

The examples I've mostly found contain something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "appService" {
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.appPlan.id
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name = "nestjs"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    remote_debugging_enabled = true
  }
}
```

I didn't find much on nodejs except [for this thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/4144), but, azure doesn't have these versions, so a bit confused: [image]

What is the `site_config` exactly? Is it specifying the `Run Time Environment` that our apps going to be using? If yes, then why is it optional? If not, then how is the RTE specified?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the available node versions first to set .

```
az webapp list-runtimes
```

[image]

- azurerm_app_service resource has been deprecated in version 3.0 . Please use resource "`azurerm_windows_web_app`" in case of windows OS and  `azurerm_linux_web_app`  in case of linux.
- remote_debugging_version  , ***`application_stack`*** are among the arguments that are supported by `site_config` block wherein application_stack has this `current_stack` option where we can set the `runtime version` or application stack settings.
- site_config block supports the following optional arguments in which
  always_on ,api_management_api_id  ,app_command_line
  ,`application_stack` ,…,cors  http2_enabled ,ip_restriction
  ,remote_debugging_version  and so on application_stack

I tried in my environment where application_stack has current_stack which is  Application Stack for the Windows Web App. Possible values are dotnet, dotnetcore, node, python, php, and java.

**NOTE** from:[windows_web_app application_stack #current_stack](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app#current_stack)

> Whilst this property is Optional omitting it can cause unexpected
> behaviour, in particular for display of settings in the Azure Portal.

when ***`current_stack`*** is set to node, `node_version` can be used to set its version and can be  14-lts, and 16-lts(which are available )

> **NOTE:** from [linux_web_app#node_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app#node_version) :
> **`10.x versions are  deprecated`** and may not work for new resources.

```
provider "azurerm" {

  features {

resource_group {
  prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }

}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "myrg"  
 location = "westus2"
}



resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "kaexampleplan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
  os_type             = "Windows"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "example" {
  name                = "kaexamplewebapp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  

  site_config {
    always_on                 = true
    application_stack {
      current_stack  = "node"
      #node_version = "16-LTS"
      
    }

  }

  app_settings = {
    WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION ="16-LTS"
  }
}
```

I tried to create '***`WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`***' through app settings , as the node version can be seen in that parameter when even created app service  using the  portal.

[image]

***App service created with Windows OS***

[image]

[image]

- Then you can check the version using this cli command:

`az webapp config appsettings list --name <webappname>--resource-group v-sakavya-Mindtree --query "[?name=='WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'].value"`

- Or to  set supported Node.js version in cloudeshell to set
  WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION

  `az webapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --settings WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION="~16"`

**Reference** :[azurerm_windows_web_app - current_stack · Issue #16222 · hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16222)

Comment: Thanks for replying, this is all useful information, but, what exactly is site_config? I mean this config has been set to always_on = true, but, I don't really get what it is.